# i have this error 'HTTP ERROR 500' when i submit this form. could anyone advise me on how to fix this?

Tags: php, contact-form

I'm new to php and want to add a contact form to my website. i found this code but it doesnt seem to submit the form correctly. it comes up with this error 'HTTP ERROR 500' and i'm nt sure how to fix it.

This form is a simple one that i'm using on my portfolio website to allow users to write a message to me as well as leaving their email address and name.

my website is on godaddy on the linux cpanel server.

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $email_from = 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net';
    $email_subject = "New form submission";
    $email_body = "User name: $name.\n".
                    "User email: $visitor_email.\n".
                        "User message: $message.\n";

    $to = "rosie.morrisgrove8@gmail.com";

    $headers = "from: $email_from \r\n";

    $headers = "Reply-to: $visitor_email \r\n";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers)

    header("location: index.html");

?>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hint: `;` - This is not a debugging service though!

Comment: Also, find out where your error logs are, and give them a read.

Comment: Nothing in your logs? Your IDE doesn't give a hint either?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `;` at the end of your second last line.